# Replace html tags having specific attributes with desired tags

Tags: html, replace

I have around 100 HTML files containing code written in mostly using `div` and `span` tags.

example:

```
<span class="Bold">Sometext <span class="Italic">Some more text</span>Even more text</span>
```

I want to replace these `span` elements with proper `<b>` and `<i>` tags in all these 100 html files. I could have used regex in notepad++ but nesting of tags is making it difficult for me to handle closing tags.

Kindly suggest how to go about it.

Comment: Find: <span class="Bold"> Replace: <b> Hit ReplaceAll. Then Find: <span class="Italic>" Replace: <i>. As for the last part, Find: </span> or </div> and replace accordingly. Just run through each one. Faster than replacing manually at least.

Comment: @Brendan: only the `</span>` matching `<span class="Bold">` needs to be replaced by `</b>`. That is my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? You can type the whole "<span class="Bold">" in the Find: form under the search option in notepad++?

Comment: @Brendan: If I replace as you suggested, after replacing both, I'm left with  lot of `</span>` tags and now I don't know which one of these closing tags was meant to close the "bold" ones and which one meant to close "italic" ones.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Here, maybe this will help? http://superuser.com/questions/549333/notepad-search-for-a-tag-and-match-till-the-end-of-the-line

Comment: Can you convert the files to an array of strings?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

How about using a regex? This would also cover the closing tags.

*Replace < span class="Bold">...< /span> with < b>...< /b>:*

```
Find: <span class="Bold">(.*)<\/span>
Replace: <b>\1<\/b>
```

[image: regex 1]

*Replace < span class="Italic">...< /span> with ...< /b>:*

```
Find: <span class="Italic">(.*)<\/span>
Replace: <i>\1<\/i>
```

[image: regex 2]

Comment: By batch I mean bulk-replace in these 100 html files. Can you please modify your code make it work for files `file1.hml`,`file2.html`,..`file100.html`. Also would this take care of closing tags too? Because only the matching `</span>`  needs to be replaced by `</b>`

Comment: No, this would obviously not cover the closing tags. To change this, you just have to copy and paste the code and modify the filter for each tag. In order to do this for each html file in a folder, you need to scan the folder and add each html file to a list. Then just iterate over this list.

Comment: Answere edited.
This should work for you and PowerShell supports regex as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a script file (JavaScript and run it once for all your pages). The only thing required would be:

```
$('span').replaceWith('b');
```

For any further clarifications this is the jquery reference.
http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Or you could create a separate js file with this code and attach it to all your files.